# Remove duplicate spaces except those belonging to initial indentation?

Tags: regular-expression

**Summary**: How to remove duplicated spaces in visual selection and/or globally while preserving the indentation?

Imagine you have a mess like this:

```
line of   text
        indented line   of text
   and some   more  random lines    of     text
```

And you need to convert it into:

```
line of text
        indented line of text
   and some more random lines of text
```

Normally, `s/\v\s{2,}/\ /g` would do the trick, but it won't preserve the indentation. Was thinking to use negative lookahead, however `:%s/\v(^)@<!\s{2,}` excludes only the first space character and I can't make it greedy: `\s+` does not work.

It might be solvable with groups, but this starts digressing into the realm of vim-script... Which might be the best way to solve it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:s/\v\S\zs\s+/ /g
```

(For a single line. Add whatever range you need.)

The `\S` (non-whitespace) atom ensures that any block of whitespace (`\s+`) is not at the start of a line. `\zs` ("replaceable part of the pattern starts here") atom ensures that the non-whitespace is excluded from the substitution, i.e. we only replace whitespace with a single space.

OR, if you prefer not to use Vim-specific features...

```
:s/\v(\S)\s+/\1 /g
```

We put the non-whitespace in a capture group and then use `\1` to include it in the replacement.

Comment: Bingo! `\zs` was the key to solving this puzzle.

Comment: Yes, but I have an alternative that doesn't require it that I'm just about to post. :)